# VIM Latex Suite repeating symbols with subscripts and superscripts

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, vim, vim-latex

I have a document that needs a lot of symbols in math environment, that have both superscripts and subscripts like `x_1^1`, `x_1^2`, `x_2^1`, `x_2^2`, with different bases. `x` could be `y`, `z`, etc....

Having to type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> all the time really hurts. Is there an easier way to type these repeating symbols this?

Just typing `x11`, `x12`, `x21`, `x22` and then replacing these strings with the respective strings with `_` and `^` (`x_1^1`, etc...) helps, but is there a more VIM way to do it?

Comment: 1) I don't have VIM but i thing you can configure the shortcuts 2) if you have \omega_1^1 repeted you can use \newcommand{\om}{\omega_1^1} and then replace \omega_1^1 bu \om

Comment: may be this help in some cases \newcommand{\s}[3]{#1^#2_#3} and than $\s x11+\s x12+ \s\beta11$

Comment: This is so cool and it's just right for me! Thanks!!! (copy/paste the comment as answer and I'll obviously accept.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Vimscript solution. In `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim`, add the following:

```
function! <SID>SubSuperscripts(keyOne, keyTwo)
  let l = strpart(getline("."), col(".")-4, 3)
  if len(l) == 3 && l[2] == a:keyOne
    return join(["\<bs>\<bs>\<bs>_", l[0], "^",  l[1]], "")
  else
    return a:keyTwo
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <buffer> <silent> & <C-R>=<SID>SubSuperscripts("^", "&")<CR>
```

Now, in insert mode the key sequence `^&` changes the preceding 2 characters into a subscript and superscript respectively. For example, inserting `x12^&` will change to `x_1^2` and `\omega11^&` will change to `\omega_1^1`.

The key sequence`^&` can be customised by changing `^` and `&` on the final line. (Don't forget the first `&` too.)