# VIM Latex Suite. Convert u1x1 to u_1(x_1)

Tags: automation, vim, vim-latex

In this question: [VIM Latex Suite repeating symbols with subscripts and superscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235259/vim-latex-suite-repeating-symbols-with-subscripts-and-superscripts) Anthony created this magnificent vimscript code:

```
function! <SID>SubSuperscripts(keyOne, keyTwo)
  let l = strpart(getline("."), col(".")-4, 3)
  if len(l) == 3 && l[2] == a:keyOne
    return join(["\<bs>\<bs>\<bs>_", l[0], "^",  l[1]], "")
  else
    return a:keyTwo
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <buffer> <silent> & <C-R>=<SID>SubSuperscripts("^", "&")<CR>
```

With this, whenever I type `x12^&` I get "instamagically" `x_1^2`! This is a life saver!
I do not know vimscript but I definitely need to learn some basic stuff there. In the meantime, can please somebody transform the above script to these variants?:

- Typing `p1x1` and then something like <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> to produce `p_1(x_1)`
- Typing `p12x12` and then something like <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> to produce `p_1^2(x_1^2)`

I have tried some things but they end with a mess. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

Copy the following into your `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` file.

Typing `p1x1` followed by <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> gives `p_1(x_1)`:

```
function! <SID>SubBrackets(keyOne, keyTwo)
  let l = strpart(getline("."), col(".")-5, 4)
  if len(l) == 4 && l[3] == a:keyOne
    return join(["\<bs>\<bs>\<bs>\<bs>_", l[0], "(",  l[1], "_", l[2], ")"], "")
  else
    return a:keyTwo
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <buffer> <silent> * <C-R>=<SID>SubBrackets("^", "*")<CR>
```

You may want to ask yourself if you will ever need to type `^*` before committing this key binding to muscle memory! Remember that you can change these key bindings.

Typing `p12x12` followed by <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> gives `p_1^2(x_1^2)`:

```
function! <SID>SubSuperBrackets(keyOne, keyTwo)
  let l = strpart(getline("."), col(".")-7, 6)
  if len(l) == 6 && l[5] == a:keyOne
    return join(["\<bs>\<bs>\<bs>\<bs>\<bs>\<bs>_", l[0], "^",  l[1],
          \ "(", l[2], "_", l[3], "^", l[4], ")"], "")
  else
    return a:keyTwo
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <buffer> <silent> ( <C-R>=<SID>SubSuperBrackets("^", "(")<CR>
```

### How it works

I actually learnt Vimscript for the purposes of answering your previous question because I thought that it would be fun. For that reason, I don't *completely* understand some of the finer details, but I'll try to explain how the main parts of the first mapping works.

Throughout, let us assume that we have inserted `p1x1` and then pressed <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>.

The most important part is:

```
inoremap <buffer> <silent> * <C-R>=<SID>SubBrackets("^", "*")<CR>
```

This is a key mapping that is called when <kbd>*</kbd> is pressed in insert mode (the `i` in `inoremap` is for **i**nsert mode). In short, this line tells vim to call the `SubBrackets` function with parameters `"^"` and `"*"`.

Now for the body of the `SubBrackets` function.

```
  let l = strpart(getline("."), col(".")-5, 4)
```

If we have `p1x1^`, this line stores `1x1^` in the variable `l`, ignoring the leading `p` because it does not need to be manipulated.

```
  if len(l) == 4 && l[3] == a:keyOne
```

This is to check that there are 4 characters in `l` (for robustness) and to ensure that the previous character inserted (`l[3]`) is `a:keyOne`, which we chose to be `"^"`. This explains how typing <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> in insert mode works.

(The `a:` prefix tells vim that `keyOne` is a local variable. A `g:` prefix refers to a global variable.)

Now, for where the magic happens:

```
    return join(["\<bs>\<bs>\<bs>\<bs>_", l[0], "(",  l[1], "_", l[2], ")"], "")
```

Remember that we want `p_1(x_1)` to replace `p1x1^` after pressing <kbd>*</kbd>. By the way that these mappings work, we need the function to return a string; the `join` function allows us to concatenate the parts in the square brackets.

In the square brackets, we simply list the keystrokes that you would need to perform to transform `p1x1^` into `p_1(x_1)`. To insert a backspace, we use `\<bs>`. I am sure you can figure the rest out.

The final part of the function:

```
  else
    return a:keyTwo
  endif
```

ensures that `*` is inserted when the preceding character is not `^`.

Comment: I don't use VIM, but you've clearly put a lot of effort into this answer. +1  Welcome to the site.

Comment: "You learnt vimscript for answering my question"? I am very flattered! vimscript seems "cryptic" (although a lot of people say it's not so difficult as it seems). I officially declare I'm in love with ViM. I use LaTeX for over a decade, but learning to edit in ViM is a breathtaking experience! Many thanks once again!

Comment: Thank you both for your kind comments! Vim and LaTeX has also been a great combination for me in the last few years, so learning a little to answer your question was very educational for myself as well!